# Volley post method return response code 500

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

Always i get below error response when using volley

```
06-24 15:06:59.244: E/Volley(12869): [2311] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://My_API
```

my code for Volley call

```
String sSignupUrl = STController.getInstance()
                .getResourceManager(LoginActivity.this)
                .getServerPropertyValue(URLConstants.API_LOGIN);
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("username", "usernam");
            params.put("passwd", "password");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                sSignupUrl, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        LogUtil.d("TAG" + response.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

I can successfully get the response when using URLConnection manager, not able to find the error, i have search through google but dint get proper solution, all answers are most welcome 
Thanks in advance

Comment: downvoter can you solve my issue, incase you feel my question is not valid ???

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709072/httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-could/39871657#39871657

Answer (score 2):

I did have the same situation. What i have done wrong is that i included `getHeaders()` in wrong `JsonObjectRequest(i.e. with a wrong url)`. But I used a custom header in my situation. Check your url. It may not be the correct one. It may not accepting this header.